# MUI Autocomplete with the top option 'Add New Customer/Vendor.'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js13

I want to create an autocomplete box that consistently displays the top option 'Add New Customer/Vendor.' This option should appear whether a search is conducted, there are no search results, or before initiating any search.

here is my code example

```
import CustomTextField from "@/components/forms/theme-elements/CustomTextField";
import { Autocomplete, Box, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { ReactSearchAutocomplete } from "react-search-autocomplete";

const AutoCompleteSearch = ({
  data,
  formValuesArray,
  setFormValuesArray,
  index,
}: any) => {
  const addNewPartner = {
    id: -1,
    first_name: "Add new",
    last_name: "Customer/Vendor",
  };
  const handleOnSelect = (event: any, item: any) => {
    console.log(item);
    if(item?.id === -1){
      alert("open modal")
    }
    else{

      // the item selected
      setFormValuesArray((prevFormValuesArray: any) => {
      const updatedFormValuesArray = [...prevFormValuesArray];
      const updatedEntry: any = { ...updatedFormValuesArray[index] };
      updatedEntry["belongsTo"] = item;
      updatedFormValuesArray[index] = updatedEntry;
      return updatedFormValuesArray;
    });
    // setDepartmentData(item._id)
  }
  };
  return (
    <Box sx={{ maxWidth: "100%" }}>
      <Autocomplete
      freeSolo
        value={formValuesArray[index]?.belongsTo}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: any) => {
          handleOnSelect(event, newValue);
        }}
       
        // sx={{ height: 40 }}

        options={[addNewPartner, ...data]}
        autoHighlight
        getOptionLabel={(option: any) =>
          `${
            option?.first_name && option?.last_name
              ? `${option.first_name} ${option.last_name} ${
                option?.type ? `(${option.type})` : ""
              }`
              : `${option.company_name} (${option.type})`
          }`
        }
        renderOption={(props, option: any) => (
          <Box
            component="li"
            sx={{ fontSize: "12px" }}
            {...props}
            key={`${option.id}`}
          >
            {option?.first_name && option?.last_name
              ? `${option.first_name} ${option.last_name} ${
                  option?.type ? `(${option.type})` : ""
                }`
              : `${option.company_name} (${option.type})`}
            {/* {option.first_name} {option.last_name} <br /> ({option.type}) */}
          </Box>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <CustomTextField
            {...params}
          
          />
        )}
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default AutoCompleteSearch;
```

"I have implemented the code I provided, but it only displays the 'Add New Customer/Vendor' option before initiating any search. However, I want it to appear in all scenarios, including after searching or when there are no search results.

[what i want is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n03pq.png)

what i am expecting is
[a simple example of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcgmc.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderGroup props like

```
        renderGroup={(params) => (
      <li key={params.key}>
          <GroupHeader onClick={() => clickAddNew()}>
            <GroupHeader2>
              New
            </GroupHeader2>

          </GroupHeader>
        <GroupItems>{params.children}</GroupItems>
      </li>
    )}
```